# Windows Phone emulator can't connect to the internet

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a fresh installation of windows 8 and I have installed visual studio 2012 and Windows Phone 8 SDK. I can successfully create projects and run them in the emulator but my emulator doesn't have internet access. At the first time i ran the emulator the prompt was given whether i want internet access or not. I selected yes but in have no internet access. I connect to the internet using a dongle. It works fine and connection has no problems as well. I cant seem to understand the problem, What are the solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

How long are you waiting from launching the emulator to trying to access the net?  The emulator takes a little while longer than you would expect to set up a connection - is that the issue?

Comment: It takes some time.. But the emulator runs. And app is also deploys successfully. But the emulator do not connect to internet. Im building an app with map control. Can;t test it out without internet.